# Sorting and Filtering Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter and sort a Pandas dataframe to clean my data. I've looked on StackOverflow and can't seem to find a method that will give me the sort and filter I need. The data I'm working with looks something like this:

```
| Name 1 | Name 2 | Score |
| ------ | ------ | ----- | 
| Amy | Jack | 2.456 | 
| Amy | Jack | 3.234 | 
| Amy | Jack | 5.124 | 
| ... | ... | ... | 
| Max | Jane | 8.569 |
| Max | Jane | 4.654 |
| Max | Jane | 6.349 |
```

What I want to do make a new dataframe out of the lowest score of every pair of names. So the resulting dataframe would be something like this:

```
| Name 1 | Name 2 | Score |
| ------ | ------ | ----- | 
| Amy | Jack | 2.456 | 
| ... | ... | ...|
| Max | Jane | 4.654 |
```

Comment: if you have more columns `df.loc[df.groupby(['Name 1', 'Name 2'])['Score'].idxmin()]`

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df = df.groupby(['Name 1', 'Name 2'], as_index = False).agg(Score = ('Score', 'min'))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Name1 Name2  Score
0   Amy  Jack  2.456
1   Max  Jane  4.654
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `sort_values()` and `groupby()` method:

```
df.sort_values(by='Score').groupby(['Name 1', 'Name 2'], as_index = False).first()
```

OR

Use `sort_values()` and `drop_duplicates()` method:

```
df.sort_values(by='Score').drop_duplicates(subset=['Name 1', 'Name 2'])
```